# Is there any sample app to parse envelope event notification from docusign in api using c#?

Tags: docusignapi

I am not able to parse docusign envelope status notification and could not find anything to do so. Is there anything already in place in library?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that uses AWS - https://github.com/docusign/connect-csharp-worker-aws
It's not a "sample app" but more of code example, and it assumes that you have a worker separately (so not getting the messages directly on your server).
The listener code is here (https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws)